# How to separate members from bots in discord member count and separate text channels from voice and categories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, discord.js, replit

So I did some research but I never found the right answers I was looking for-
Here is the complete code:

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")
const moment = require("moment")
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  console.log(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
  const messageEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(" Server Information ")
  .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
  .addFields(
    {name: "Server Name:", value: `${message.guild.name}`, inline: true},

    {name: "Server Owner:", value: `${message.guild.owner.user.tag}`, inline: true},

    {name: "Server Created:", value: `${moment(message.guild.createdAt).format("ddd, MMM DD, YYYY H:M A")}`},

    {name: "Member Count:", value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`, inline: true},

    {name: "Emoji Count:", value: `${message.guild.emojis.cache.size}`, inline: true},

    {name: "Channel Count:", value: `${message.guild.channels.cache.size}`},

    {name: "Role Count:", value: `${message.guild.roles.cache.size}`, inline: false},

    {name: "Roles:", value: `${message.guild.roles.cache.sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).map(r => '<@&'+r.id+'>').join('  ').slice(0,-24)}`, inline: false},
    
  )
  .setColor("#FFFF66")
  .setFooter("ID: " + message.guild.id)
  .setTimestamp()

  message.channel.send(messageEmbed)
}


exports.help = {
    name: "serverinfo"
}

exports.conf = {
    aliases: ["serverinfo"]
}
```

For member count:  `` {name: "Member Count:", value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`, inline: true}, `` shows bots and members both without filters

And for channels: `` {name: "Channel Count:", value: `${message.guild.channels.cache.size}`}, `` shows both voice channels and categories.

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 2):

You can count them manually instead, like:

```
var nonBotMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size
```

and use the same thing for counting only specific channel types.

Comment: I tried that but im getting this: [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/924212256835780638/926662959130890300/unknown.png)

Comment: Hold on, @Itzkaiiii let me try it in a test server with my test bot and I'll post a solution...

Comment: `const nonBotMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size`
        `console.log(nonBotMembers)`

Works for me. Maybe it's a bug on your end.

Comment: Is your bot able to access "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT"? Discord considers details about server members as sensitive information so you need to enable access to than manually from https://discord.com/developers/applications/ .